# Regex: Matching the closest value backwards

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to match all section names that contains a certain value, as here:

```
section aaa:
   some values
   value 5
section bbb:
   more values
   value 6
section ccc:
   some values
   value 5
section ddd:
   more values
   value 6
```

For example:

```
section (.*?):.*?value 6  (DOTALL|MULTILINE)
```

will match `aaa`, `ccc` instead of `bbb`, `ddd`.

Is there a way to match `bbb` and `ddd`?

Thanks

UPDATE:
  there are solutions (that work) that are based on the assumption that values lines don't contain colon or don't start with the space. However is there a way to match the `value 6` and get the closest section that precedes it, i.e. even if values contain colon or are not indented?

nhahtdh's answer: You don't search backward with regex. There is look-behind (in this case, it would require variable width look-behind), but it is extremely inefficient, and Python default re module does not support look-behind of any form

MY CONCLUSION:
  this can be done either with pure regex with the above assumptions, or (my preferred) is to use combined regex-python approach suggestged by drewk (which also has some assumptions, namely that section has to contain `value`)

UPDATE 2:
Here is what I ended up with. It seems to work with none of the above limitations. It does have the assumption the the values cannot have a line starting with `section .*:`. We are matching the section up to the next section but not including it (by using `(?=...)` syntax) and, in order to match the last section we have `\Z` which is the end of string.

```
for m in re.finditer(r'^section (.*?):(.*?)(?=(^section .*:)|\Z)', str1, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL):
    section = m.group(1)
    values = m.group(2)    
    if "value 6" in values:
        print section
```

Comment: Why don't you just parse it into a dictionary?

Comment: The match is actually a part of replacement - I want to delete all the sections from a big file that contain a certain value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the last section:

```
print re.findall(r'^section (\w+):',tgt,flags=re.MULTILINE)[-1]
```

With your edit, this does it:

```
import re

tgt='''\
section aaa:
   some values
   value 5
section bbb:
   more values
   value 6
section ccc:
   some values
   value 5
section ddd:
   more values
   value 6'''

pat=re.compile(r'^section (\w+):.*?value (\d+)',flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

print [(m.group(1),m.start(),m.end()) 
          for m in pat.finditer(tgt)
          if m.group(2)=='6']
```

Prints:

```
[('bbb', 39, 77), ('ddd', 117, 155)]
```

***Edit***

Look ma, no colons or indent:

import re

```
tgt='''\
section aaa:
   some values
   value 5
section bbb
   more values
value 6
section ccc:
   some values
   value 5
section ddd:
   more values
   value 6'''

pat=re.compile(r'^section (\w+).*?^\s*value (\d+)',flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

print [(m.group(1),m.start(),m.end()) 
          for m in pat.finditer(tgt)
          if m.group(2)=='6']
```

Same output

***Edit 2***

If it is important to filter out sections that might not have a matching 'value' section, use two regexes with the first with a forward look ahead:

```
import re

tgt='''\
section aaa:
   some values

section bbb:
   more values
   value 6
section ccc:
   some values
   value 5
section ddd:
   more values
   value 6'''

pat1=re.compile(r'^section (\w+):(.*?)(?=section|\Z)',flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
pat2=re.compile(r'^\s*value (\d+)',flags=re.MULTILINE)

for m in pat1.finditer(tgt):
    m2=re.search(r'^\s*value (\d+)',m.group(2),flags=re.MULTILINE)
    if m2 and m2.group(1)=='6':
        print m.group(1)
```

prints `bbb` and `ddd`

Comment: Thanks, looks like combining python logic with regex is the cleanest in this case, pure regex could work but gets complicated and has certain assumptions (that the content of the section has a certain format)

Comment: If some section misses `value`, the first value from the following sections will be taken, and if it happens that it equals `6`, the current section will be output though it is missing the value parameter.

Comment: For example try this code with the input `'''\
section aaa:
   some values
section bbb:
   more values
section ccc:
   some values
   value 6'''`. The output is `[('aaa', 0, 94)]`, though `aaa` has no `value` parameter.

Comment: @ovgolovin: yeah this is the assumption (limitation) here.

Answer (score 3):

```
section ([^:]+):[^:]+value 6  (DOTALL|MULTILINE)
```

of course, this works only if you don't have colons in the "more values" part

Comment: It does work! It is based on the trick to explicitly describe the format of the section content (in this case that values lines don't contain colon). The question is however is it possible to do what logicaly seems to be easy: to find "value 6" and the search backwards for first matching section:

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the section name doesn't contain any `:`, and a valid section must be declared with `section` **at the beginning of the line**, this solution will find all the names of the sections with given value. The regex must be compiled with `MULTILINE` option.

```
^section ([^:\n]+):.*\n( +.*\n)*( +value 6\b)
```

Explanation:

- `^section ([^:\n]+):.*\n` searches for lines begins with `section` , followed by the section name (assumed not to contain `:` or new line character), followed by `:`. The rest `.*\n` matches the rest of the `section` line.
- `( +.*\n)*` matches the lines with at least 1 space of indentation. It ensures that we don't "spill over" to the next section.
- `( +value 6\b)` matches (part of) the line containing the desired value. `\b` makes sure `6` is not followed by another digit (63), or alphabet character (6a), or underscore (6_).

This solution will work even if `some values` contains colon `:`.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/rL7oY5)

Note that effect of `\b` may vary if `LOCALE` flag or `UNICODE` flag are used.

Comment: It does work! It is based on the trick to explicitly describe the format of the section content (in this case to start with the space). The question is however is it possible to do what loggicaly seems to be easy: to find "value 6" and the search backwards for first matching section:

Comment: @Ivan: You don't search backward with regex. There is look-behind (in this case, it would require variable width look-behind), but it is extremely inefficient, and Python default `re` module does not support look-behind of any form.

Answer (score 0):

Why `aaa` and `ccc` are matched? Let's create a second group around second `.*?` and see what it outputs:

```
>>> re.findall(r'section (.*?):(.*?)value 6',text, re.M | re.S)
[('aaa', '\n   some values\n   value 5\nsection bbb:\n   more values\n   '), ('ccc', '\n   some values\n   value 5\nsection ddd:\n   more values\n   ')]
```

From this we can see that the second group captures more than it should.

To avoid this, ensure that each `.` in the second non-greedy consumer is not followed by `^section` for it not to bypass the beginning of a new section while searching for `value 6` and the first one doesn't consume `:`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'section ([^:]*?):(?:.(?!^section))*?value 6',text, re.M | re.S)
['bbb', 'ddd']
```

Comment: @Jerry The question has been edited, and the sample was different.

Comment: It still doesn't match the initial sample. Only two more sections were added, one containing `value 6`.